# Simple Qt HTML5

Tags: c++, html, qt

I have created a new HTML5 Qt app in Qt creator. The version I have is

```
Qt Creator 3.1.2 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.3.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)
Built on Jun 23 2014 at 04:13:10
From revision a791e851a7
```

I don't seem to be able to get any code in `<?c` tags to work within the `HTML` file.

For Instance I have this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <a id="quit">X</a>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>HTML5</h1>
    <h1>World</h1>
    <?c cout << "Hello World" ?>

</body>
</html>
```

But I never see the "Hello World" that should be produced by `cout`. Why is that?

Comment: You say "HTML5", but your DOCTYPE is pretty specifically saying "XHTML 1.0". This might be incidental to your question, but there it is :)

Comment: Oh Yeah, That's strange considering the file was auto-generated by Qt Creator within a HTML5 project. I've tried without that and it still doesn't work

Comment: I haven't seen that `<?c`-syntax before, but found this document: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336018/Building-C-Applications-with-HTML5 It uses `out` rather than `cout`. Is that your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the link but still no job changing to `out` and rebuilding.

Comment: Where did you read about these code tags? Remember that you're still building a *Qt* application. Whatever you do must be supported by Qt! Unless you have URLs to Qt documentation demonstrating this technique, you are out of luck here.

Comment: It looks like your HTML is meant be processed by some kind of C interpreter on server side or something (like <?php ... ?>). Qt does not process your html, it just passes it to the WebKit browser as it is.